# Getting argument missing error In ParamgridBuilder on Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am currently implementing Gradientboost classification model in Pyspark.Based on kaggle dataset My current final columns after fitting pipeline is 
[image]

I am now trying parameter tuning by PARAMGRIDBUILD. here is my Parameter grid build code

```
param_grid=ParamGridBuilder.addGrid(gradboost.maxDepth,[2,3,4]).addGrid(gradboost.minInfoGain,[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).addGrid(gradboost.stepSize,[0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]).build()
```

and  I am  getting below error

```
  ****param_grid=ParamGridBuilder.addGrid(gradboost.maxDepth,[2,3,4]).addGrid(gradboost.minInfoGain,[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).addGrid(gradboost.stepSize,[0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]).build()
TypeError: addGrid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'****
```

I did not use Paramgridbuild before. does this array values represent each column of my current dataframe? kindly help me to figure out the error and give me the basic concept of using this values. Here is my full code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,VectorIndexer,OneHotEncoder,VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder,CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator





spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp").appName("Gradientboostapp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data= spark.read.csv("C:/Users/codemen/Desktop/Timeseries Analytics/liver_patient.csv",header=True, inferSchema=True)
#data.show()
print(data.count())
#data.printSchema()
print("After deleting  null  values")

data=data.na.drop()
print(data.count())
data.show(5)

gender_column=data.columns[1:2]
#print(categorical_column)

stringindexstage=[StringIndexer(inputCol=c,outputCol='genderindexed')for c in gender_column]
#print(stringindexstage)
stringindexstage=stringindexstage+[StringIndexer(inputCol='category',outputCol='classlabel')]
for x in stringindexstage:
    data=x.fit(data).transform(data)
    data.show(3)
#data.show(3)
#print ("Type of",type(stringindexstage))

onehotencoderstage=[OneHotEncoder(inputCol='genderindexed', outputCol='onehot'+c) for c in gender_column]

for onehot in onehotencoderstage:
    data=onehot.transform(data)
    data.show()

#vector assembler

print("data current")
data.show(3)
feature_column=['Age','onehotGender','Total_Bilirubin', 'Direct_Bilirubin', 'Alkaline_Phosphotase', 'Alamine_Aminotransferase', 'Aspartate_Aminotransferase', 'Total_Protiens',
                'Albumin', 'Albumin_and_Globulin_Ratio']
print(feature_column)

#Vector Assembler stage

vectorassmblestage=[VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_column,outputCol="features")]


#pipeline model

#allstages=stringindexstage+onehotencoderstage+vectorassmblestage
#for i in allstages:


#
pipelinestage=Pipeline(stages=vectorassmblestage)
#
# #fitting variable
pipelinemodel=pipelinestage.fit(data)
#
# #Transform Data
#
finalcolumns=feature_column+['features','classlabel']
#
dataframe=pipelinemodel.transform(data).select(finalcolumns)
print("final column print")
dataframe.show(5)

#splitting data into train test

(traindata, testdata)=dataframe.randomSplit([0.7,0.3],seed=1234)
#gradientboosting
gradboost=GBTClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='classlabel',maxIter=10)


#parameter  tuning

param_grid=ParamGridBuilder.addGrid(gradboost.maxDepth,[2,3,4]).addGrid(gradboost.minInfoGain,[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).addGrid(gradboost.stepSize,[0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]).build()

##Evaluation
print("Evaluation stage")

evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol='prediction')

#crossvalidation state
print("cross validation stage")

crossvalidation=CrossValidator(estimator=gradboost,estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,evaluator=evaluator)
crossvalidateData=crossvalidation.fit(dataframe)

##prediction on Training Data
print("Prediction in Training data ....")

predictTrain=crossvalidateData.transform(traindata)
predictTrain.show(10)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For starters it looks like you need to call `ParamGridBuilder()` with parentheses

so;

```
param_grid = ParamGridBuilder() \
     .addGrid(...)
```